# Unable to retrieve data from database but when name changed i can retrieve

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have this piece of code

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

public class OracleCon {

public static void main(String args[])
{

 try {

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

String url= "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";
String user = "scott";
String pswd = "tiger";

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pswd);
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String query = "select * from testtable";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while(rs.next())
    {
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+", " +rs.getString(2)+ " ,"+rs.getInt(3));
    }
    con.close();
    stmt.close();
    rs.close();

} catch (Exception ex) {
     System.out.println("Error with connection: "+ex);
}
```

I have used the required jar(s). The code works fine with another table (saurabhtable) which has data. When I try to run this same code for another table(testtable) it doesnt return selected rows though the table has data in it. On again changing the table name to saurabhtable, it returns the result.
I wrote the code independently for the testtable but it was not running. So i happen to change the table name

what could be the reason?

Comment: When you execute `select * from testtable` from sqlplus, what does it return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did some R&D and I got the answer. I did commit at the sql prompt for the testtable and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try using schema_name.table_name. 
(P.S I didn't have enough reputation to comment hence answered it, Although this is not a answer, I feel this is the first point to troubleshoot)

Comment: but if it is working with another name of table than adding/not adding schema_name should not be a problem. I think so.